# Create LiveConnectClient

Tags: onedrive

I'm using OneDrive Live sdk 5.6 to make api calls. To create a new LiveConnectClient, his constructor needs a session . To create this session we need an authorization code which is generated after user accepts to share his info with onedrive application. 
The problem is that any method from onedrive needs a client (methods = download,upload,get user info etc.). 
All I want is to store access token/refresh token to create a LiveConnectClient and then call all other methods.
Can this be done?

Why we need access token if it isn't used?

My code is:

```
LiveAuthClient AuthClient new LiveAuthClient(clientIdFromOneDriveApp);

//create session based on authentication code from web browser uri

LiveConnectSession session = AuthClient.ExchangeAuthCodeAsync(new AuthResult(uriFromWebBrowser).AuthorizeCode).Result;
//store access token

string accessToken = session.AccessToken;

//create live client based on session
LiveConnectClientliveConnectClient = new LiveConnectClient(session);
```

Create folder method :

```
Dictionary<string, object> folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

folderData.Add("name", newFolderName);

LiveOperationResult operationResult = webBrowserWindow.liveConnectClient.PostAsync(uploadPath, folderData).Result;
```

So , the only thing I need is LiveConnectClient to create folder. I don't need an access token.

Comment: Daniel, I'm not sure what your question is, could you clarify what you would like to understand?

Comment: Hi Peter, what I want is to create an offline LiveConnectClient based on access token . Because I don't want the user to give consent only once ,when a refresh token is retrieved. Then based on refresh token ,I create an access token and then create the client . I've found this ,but I don't know where to use the access token : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694244.aspx . Thank you